How to add a default ripple effect to buttons in an Android app?
I'm an iOS developer, but currently working on an Android app and found inconsistencies in the default ripple effect behavior on buttons across different devices.
On my testing device, an LG VELVET with Android 12, the buttons in my app have a ripple effect by default when I tap them. The code I'm using is very simple:
import android.util.Log
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.material.ripple.rememberRipple
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier

@Composable
private fun ChangeAccountClickableImage(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    resourceId: Int,
    contentDescription: String
) {
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = resourceId),
        contentDescription = contentDescription,
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(40.dp)
            .clickable(
                interactionSource = MutableInteractionSource(),
                indication = rememberRipple(),
                onClick = onClick
            )
    )
}

I also saw a related issue, Click indication is hardly to see since Android 13 June Update, where the ripple effect is not clearly visible on some devices after the Android 13 June update. To further investigate, I installed the Compose Material Catalog app from the Play Store and checked if the default ripple effect is applied on my LG VELVET and Pixel 7a devices. Unfortunately, only the LG VELVET had the ripple effect, while the Pixel 7a did not.
In my code, I'm using the rememberRipple() function, but I noticed that it's deprecated. So, I'm wondering if there are any other workarounds or best practices to ensure a consistent default ripple effect on buttons in my Android app.
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
